# mysql - concat with year & week function

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select concat(yearval,weekval) as val1,concat(year(curdate()),week(curdate())) as val2 from wbr_weekly;
+-------+--------+
| val1  | val2   |
+-------+--------+
| 20161 | 201614 |
| 20162 | 201614 |
| 20163 | 201614 |
| 20164 | 201614 |
| 20165 | 201614 |
| 20161 | 201614 |
| 20162 | 201614 |
| 20163 | 201614 |
| 20164 | 201614 |
| 20165 | 201614 |
| 20161 | 201614 |
| 20162 | 201614 |
| 20163 | 201614 |
| 20164 | 201614 |
| 20165 | 201614 |
+-------+--------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And

```
mysql> select concat(yearval,weekval) as val1 from wbr_weekly where concat(yearval,weekval) < concat(year(curdate()),week(curdate()));
+-------+
| val1  |
+-------+
| 20161 |
| 20161 |
| 20161 |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

my aim is to return all the weeks less than current week.I thought second query will do what want . but it didn't. Can someone explain what went wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is doing a string comparison instead of the desired numeric comparison you want.  When you compare the string "20165" with the "201614", "20165" is greater than "201614".

My advice would be to either:

1. If these are numeric fields in your table, don't turn them into strings for the WHERE clause.  Try this instead: `where yearval < year(curdate()) OR (yearval = year(curdate()) AND weekval < week(curdate()))`
2. Alternatively, when turning the fields into strings you should pad the fields with leading zeros where appropriate.  This would turn "20165" into "201605", which is less then "201614".

Comment: Thanks Dave. ! .. Accepted

Answer (score 1):

In a string comparison, "20161", "20162" etc. will always be lexigraphically smaller than "201614". You need to pad the week number with a leading zero to make the comparison work: "201601", "201602" and so on:

```
select concat(yearval,weekval) as val1 from wbr_weekly 
    where concat(yearval, right(concat('0', weekval), 2)) 
      < concat(year(curdate()),week(curdate()));
```